# ImageView doesn't overlay on GoogleMap

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Even if I change a **Parent Layout** into Relative Layout, My ImageView doesn't shown in the front.

I guess this is a minimal bug which I don't know.

For Example:

[image: HERE'S THE IMAGE]

There's a fragment(map), and a Button, and a legend of this map.

Button is normally shown at the runtime, but legend doesn't.

For more information, here's the xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="select"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="legend"
            android:translationZ="1000dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/legend_imageview" />
```

Comment: change the fragment `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and put your button and ImageView on a LinearLayout.

Comment: Do you know [What does TranslationZ actually do in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29848276/1318946)? Remove `android:translationZ="1000dp"` and Try

Comment: @PratikButani OK Wait a sec please I'll try. BTW, thanks for the information about TranslationZ.

Comment: @PratikButani Still, the ImageView doesn't popup.

Comment: @PratikButani Is there a reason why I have to put button & Imageview into fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Here's the answer.

It's simple.

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/legend_imageview"
```

has to be changed into

```
android:src="@drawable/legend_imageview"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for layout

**Change Relativelayout to framelayout**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="select"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="legend"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/legend_imageview" />
```