# Stack images one over the other. Z-Axis in android

Tags: android

So I am really new to Android, but I have created the desired effect in xCode.

What I am trying to figure out is what is the equivalent to ZStack() in xCode for Android.

I am trying to stack an image over another when required.

In xCode the use of ZStack will allow this, in fact it allows anything to be stacked over one another. How does this get done Android?

UPDATE  Added image of iOS view using ZStack.
[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with android studio, nor xCode really. those are IDE's used to develop apps, specifically android and ios apps. what you're developing _for_ is android, so you're looking for ways to achieve this _in android_

Comment: `Lastly, is there a quick method to blur an image in Android, again in xCode its just a property, is that the same for Android?` this is another question entirely, should probably ask this in another post or it'll get closed as needing focus

Comment: Removed the blur portion of the question, thx

Comment: perhaps you're looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848276/what-does-translationz-actually-do-in-android?

Comment: if you can post an image of what you're trying to achieve, we can try help you do that

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Jetpack Compose**, there's `Box` composable for this.

When the content of `Box` has more than one layout child the layout children will be stacked one on top of the other in the same order they are declared.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout

https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/layout/box/

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(1f)
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = "background"
    )
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
        contentDescription = "foreground"
    )
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.staunty_bb),
        contentDescription = "Image caption"
    )
}
```

---

If you're using View system, then there's `FrameLayout` for the purpose of stacking child `View`(s)/Layout(s).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout

Comment: as I said, im new to Android, so I am not sure what Jetpack Compose is? I am currently just using Android Studio, is that an add on to that? Is that something that is free?

Comment: Jetpack Compose is modern UI toolkit for Android. It's analogous to SwiftUI for Apple in many ways. Yes, it's free. Check it out here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

Comment: Here is a codelab tutorial to get started with `Jetpack Compose` in Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#0

Comment: Last question, does this work with Java or only Kotlin? I have my app in Java.

Comment: Compose is for Kotlin only. I'd highly encourage you to learn Kotlin for Android development. It's way more fun to write code in Kotlin over Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout to stack views on top of each other. Something like the below XML:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="+id/rootView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

   <AppCompatImageView
       android:id="+id/imageViewOne"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <AppCompatImageView
       android:id="+id/imageViewTwo"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <AppCompatImageView
       android:id="+id/imageViewThree"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Once you have the basic understanding how different view groups like FrameLayout, LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, then ConstraintLayout will be a good option to practice.

Comment: I have a question in regards to your use of `AppCompatImageView` vs `ImageView `. When I used `AppCompatImageView` the image is not viewable in the designer and app crashes when i run it, vs if I use `ImageView` which displays the images successfully in the designer and when the app runs?  Can someone tell me why `AppCompatImageView` is there for?

Comment: As far as I understand, `AppCompatImageView` is used to provide support for some features which do not work on older platform versions. Things like dynamic background tint etc. It is completely fine to use `ImageView`. The `androidx.appcompat.*` package contains the app compat versions of the views to provide backward compatability for some APIs which otherwise would not work.

Comment: I am curious about the crash. Did you happen to get logs for the crash? It might have crashed if it was used in a layout which has a parent activity extending `Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity`. It is the similar case with AppCompatActivity also. It is used to provide some backported features which would normally work on newer android versions and not the older versions.

Comment: this is the error message I get `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class AppCompatImageView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class AppCompatImageView
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.AppCompatImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.replaysport.pickemparty-hyXGz_8EtlTSNapkmD1NMA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.replaysport.pickemparty-hyXGz_8EtlTSNapkmD1NMA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]`

Comment: Weird, the AppCompatImageView is not being added in the class file. Can you try extending your activity class with AppCompatActivity?

Comment: I beleive it already is `public class PicksheetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`