# Image hiding under button android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Image view is hiding under the button what changes I can do so that the image view can be above the button view pager also have bottom padding so that button can properly accommodate. The image is showing on the other parts but not above the button.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".McqActivity"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        >
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    
    
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/starFirst"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24"
                />                  
    
    
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/questions_view_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            >
    
        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
        
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Drop a screenshot of the layout here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` and other `layout_constraint...` won't work inside `RelativeLayout`, these are desired to work with `ConstraintLayout` as strict parent. if you want to align two `View`s next to/below/above inside `RelativeLayoyut` you have to use other attributes, e.g.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/starFirst"
android:layout_above="@+id/starFirst"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/starFirst"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/starFirst"
```

note that every attr which starts with `layout_` is desired to be read by strict parent, not by `View` which have such attrs set. every `ViewGroup` have own set of such

edit: turned out that this is an `elevation` case/issue (Z axis), so useful attributes are

```
android:translationZ="100dp"
android:elevation="100dp"
```

Comment: I have added android:layout_below="@+id/starFirst" in button my image view go above the button and as I do android:layout_above="@+id/starFirst" my button disappears and only the image is showing I want that my image should be shown above the button please help if you can

Comment: I can only suggest double check params and ids, it very weird that one attr is working, another similar not at all... sadly I don't have any other clue, sorry

Comment: well, I do have one... exchange `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: or... maybe I misunderstood you and you want to place both `View`s one ON another, not above or below... inspect `translationZ` and `elevation` params. I you want to cover button with some image then set for image `android:translationZ="100dp"`

Comment: Yes I want to cover the button with multiple images and after that disable and enable them programmatically

Comment: `MaterialButton` have some `translationZ` and `elevation` values set by default, it will be drawn on most of other `View`s. just use one of these attributes with higher value (`100dp` will be sufficient for shure) for image

Comment: [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping) you have some info about elevation, [HERE](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/07/android-elevation-and-translationz.html) some example and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848276/what-does-translationz-actually-do-in-android) SO topic with some relevant info

Comment: Thank you sir for your help now it's working fine